# Best way to implement navigation in mvvm for wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I implement MVVM in my current WPF application assignment.

I created a base class which inherit Window and then every other window inherit this class.

```
public class ApplicationScreenBase : Window
    {
        public ApplicationScreenBase()
        {
            AppMessenger.Register(this, OnMessageToApp);
            this.Unloaded += ApplicationScreenBase_Unloaded;
        }

        private void ApplicationScreenBase_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AppMessenger.Unregister(this, OnMessageToApp);
        }

        private void OnMessageToApp(AppMessage message)
        {
            switch (message.MessageType)
            {
                case AppMessageType.Navigate:
                    {
                        var CurrentWindow = Activator.CreateInstance(Locator.NavigationPageLocator.LocateNavigateTypeByEnum((NavigationScreens)message.MessageData)) as Window;
                        CurrentWindow.Show();
                        this.Close();
                        break;
                    }
                case AppMessageType.NewWindow:
                    {
                        var CurrentWindow = Activator.CreateInstance(Locator.NavigationPageLocator.LocateNavigateTypeByEnum((NavigationScreens)message.MessageData)) as Window;
                        CurrentWindow.Show();
                        break;
                    }
                case AppMessageType.MessageBox:
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(message.MessageData.ToString());
                        break;
                    }
                case AppMessageType.Close:
                    {
                        this.Close();
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my navigation class which return me Type of window to open.

```
public static class NavigationPageLocator
    {
        public static Type LocateNavigateTypeByEnum(NavigationScreens navigationPage)
        {
            switch (navigationPage)
            {
                case NavigationScreens.LoginOnline:
                    return typeof(LoginOnline);
                case NavigationScreens.MainWindow:
                    return typeof(MainWindow);
                case NavigationScreens.Home:
                    return typeof(Home);
            }
            return default(Type);
        }
    }
```

This is how I use AppMessenger

```
public enum AppMessageType
    {
        Navigate,
        NewWindow,
        Close,
        MessageBox
    }
    public class AppMessage
    {
        public AppMessageType MessageType { get; set; }
        public object MessageData { get; set; }
    }
    public class AppMessenger
    {
        public static void Register(object recipient, Action<AppMessage> action)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register<AppMessage>(recipient, action);
        }

        public static void Unregister(object recipient, Action<AppMessage> action)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Unregister<AppMessage>(recipient, action);
        }

        public static void Send(AppMessage message)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Send<AppMessage>(message);
        }
```

And this is some way I control the flow from ViewModel-

```
AppMessenger.Send(new AppMessage() { MessageType = AppMessageType.Navigate, MessageData = NavigationScreens.Home });
```

Now the problem is I register to window successfully and I found that a single instance of AppMessenger is register to per Window but when I notify messenger to invoke some event it fires twice.
For e.g.

```
AppMessenger.Send(new AppMessage() { MessageType = AppMessageType.MessageBox, MessageData = "Authentication failed." });
```

This will show two time MessageBox.

Why did it fire twice. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here i found my solution

```
 public ApplicationScreenBase()
        {
            this.Loaded +=ApplicationScreenBase_Loaded;
            this.Unloaded += ApplicationScreenBase_Unloaded;
            this.Activated += ApplicationScreenBase_Activated;
            this.Deactivated += ApplicationScreenBase_Deactivated;
        }

        void ApplicationScreenBase_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AppMessenger.Unregister(this, OnMessageToApp);
        }

        void ApplicationScreenBase_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AppMessenger.Register(this, OnMessageToApp);
        }
```

What is happening is, if i open two windows then AppMessenger send message twice as both windows are currently registered with AppMessenger. So using Window life cycle i unregister Appmessenger to the window which is in background and register which is in forground this way, only one window will be registered to the AppMessenger, but i doubt what happen if both windows are in foreground in minimize state. Hope this may help someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

You consider another class (WindowManger) which can main the windows for you. You are creating a new window for navigation as well. Here you could have checked from the WindowManager if the window is already present.

Comment: Thanks please check my question i found new things in my problem

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the problem with navigation is you want to decouple the often complex navigation logic with the UI and business logic associated to each "page" of content.  This is essentially achieved through your `NavigationPageLocator` class, and a message based communication system.

You seem to be going along the right lines to implementing your own solution, although you may find yourself having to do a lot of "plumbing" to achieve some more advanced scenarios.  You may want to take a look at the [PRISM documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) regarding navigation in WPF applications, which offers a ready-implemented solution.